# How can I use my blender animation on my website?

Tags: animation, export, video

I'm extremely new to blender and need to know, before I get going, if it is possible to use my animation on websites.
I develop websites and am looking for an animation software to make my websites even better, so before I start putting a lot of time into learning blender, I need to make sure it is possible to use it on my website.

Comment: Check the above link. It is completely legal to use any product you create with Blender commercially.

Comment: It's not clear whether the question is about legal issues, or technical issues.

Comment: Well, it began as a question of legal and technical, I got the answer to the legal part, still unsure about the technical. but thank you guys for helping!

Comment: Blender outputs images and videos, not HTML or java or anything. So if you can use images or videos, blender can help.